# Getting time difference between two time strings with Javascript

Tags: javascript, datetime, time, date-difference

I'm attempting to create a form with 3 inputs (2 unlocked and one locked) where you will input 2 `times` for example `7:30AM` and `4:00PM` and it will generate the difference between the times in `seconds` in the 3rd box.

The problem is, I can't seem to get a working method to actually calculate the time difference.

```
<script language="javascript" type="text/javascript">
$(document).ready(function(){
    function UpdateHours(){ 

        var start = $("#time1").val();
        var end = $("#time2").val();

        var dtStart = new Date("7/20/2015 " + start);
        var dtEnd = new Date("7/20/2015 " + end);

        var diff = dtEnd - dtStart;

        $("#totalTime").val(diff);
    }
    $(document).on("change, keyup", "#time1", UpdateHours);
    $(document).on("change, keyup", "#time2", UpdateHours);
});
</script>  

<input id="time1" type="text" />
<input id="time2" type="text" />
<input id="totalTime" readonly="readonly" />
```

This is what I have tried so far among other things. Could I get some help, please?

Comment: What is the `hours1` variable? Why would you not display the value of `diff`?

Comment: thatidiotguy - those were just different things I tried. When I display diff it displays `30600000` which I can't make any sense of.

Comment: `30600000` these would be milliseconds, divide them by 1000 and you would get seconds, if thats what you meant by `which I can't make any sense of.`

Comment: Math.floor(30600000 / (100*60*60)) = 85 hours

Comment: @TimothyLee try the updated optimized code

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```js
$(document).ready(function(){
  
  var $time1 = $("#time1");
  var $time2 = $("#time2");
  var $diff = $("#totalTime");

  function updateHours(){   

        var dtStart = new Date("7/20/2015 " + $time1.val());
        var dtEnd = new Date("7/20/2015 " + $time2.val());

        var diff = dtEnd - dtStart;

        $diff.val(diff/1000);
  }
    $time1.add($time2).on("change, keyup", function(){
        if($time1.val() && $time2.val()){
            updateHours()
        }
    });
   
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<input id="time1" type="text" placeholder="7:00 PM"/>
<input id="time2" type="text" placeholder="8:00 PM"/>
<input id="totalTime" readonly="readonly" />
```

Comment: Thank you for the suggestions and pointers. I have it fully working the way its meant to now :).

Comment: The issue I had was I didn't know how to convert from milliseconds, so I kept getting the wrong numbers because I was converting incorrectly.

Answer (score 2):

The problem you are having is that you are subtracting an object from another object. I don't know what JavaScript decides to do in this case, but to be safe you should not rely on that behavior even if it did work. What you should be doing is this:

```
var diff = dtEnd.getTime() - dtStart.getTime();
```

`diff` will then be the number of milliseconds between the two date objects.